# Multiple views for the same form in a web application

Tags: php, design-patterns, model-view-controller, web-applications, architecture

I have a situation where I have several ways to perform the same activity in my php web app.

There is the "Manage Widgets" section of the app which has a form for creating new widgets and a list of existing widgets.

Then somewhere else in the app there is a button that pops up a dialog to add a new widget.

Then on the home page of the app there is another place where a form is embedded to add a widget (think home page portal).

My question is: What is the best practice for this?  In this case all of the forms will be essentially the same.  So my first instinct is to use the same code for all three of these scenarios.  On the other hand, space on the home page could be smaller and layouts may have to differ between the three.

So even though it would be repetition, is it better to duplicate this form 3 times (there is a proper model layer, so the duplicated code would not include the logic to add/edit the widget)?  Or try to force a single view in all of these scenarios?  Both seem wrong to me and I am hoping for some ideas to discover some sort of middle ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to have the markup (not the styles) for the form as a standalone file, which can then be included from anywhere you like.

You can then use AJAX to submit the form to a specific PHP script that handles the form submission and returns a meaningful JSON response. You can then display and style this JSON response on the page in question.

This way you have a single form (that can be styled differently) and a single handler for any view that's required to use the form.

Comment: This is the way I ended up going.  I am using sort of this pattern with jquery/ajax to make reusable controls anyway. So, I could make the basic form a control and pull that into each view with different CSS as needed.

Answer (score 0):

i mean, the best way is compose form from other forms (Dont repeat yourself). You can use different templates for same form to change appearance of final form.

For example/idea you can check forms what is used in Nette Framework (http://doc.nette.org/en/forms)

T.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just changing the styles, not the markup, I think the best approach is to add a specific class to the form element and then use Javascript (not Ajax, justa Javascript) to alternate between these clases as you need.

If your application do not use Ajax at all and you just generate web pages with PHP, is a simple matter of decide which class you form shoud have.

In CSS, you do something like this:

```
form.main { ... }
/* main form rules */

form.other { ... }
/* other form rules */
```